# Java persistence error no valid providers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to follow along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHohVibqePw&t=2s) tutorial. when they run the code it is successful. when I run the code I get an error that says `WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.` I looked into the documentation and explicitly defined the entity/provider. I do have some red error font for `.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` because it says it can't resolve the class. Here's the main class

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa")
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public static void main(String[] args){

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa");

    Client client = new Client();
    client.setId(2);
    client.setName("bob");

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    bank.setName("wells fartgo");

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    entityManager.persist(client);
    entityManager.persist(bank);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

the persistence.xml which is in /resources/WEB_INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
        value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>
        <!--use second level cache-->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <!--use 3rd level cache-->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

also my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>java.jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0-alpha3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

the classes in main (bank/client) just have getters and setters so there's nothing wrong there. if anyone could let me know how to successfully run this demo that would be great. thanks.

Comment: To start with, don't use something so new that it's an alpha version; use the 5.x series. Additionally, your `type:pom` is telling Maven not to pull in the actual `hibernate-core`, just some metadata. Remove it and you should be fine. Finally, if you're using Spring Boot, don't use that tutorial, and just add `spring-boot-starter-jpa`.

Comment: @chrylis I made the changes you suggested and now I'm getting this error 

`Jul 10, 2019 10:36:36 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa
 ...]
Jul 10, 2019 10:36:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
Jul 10, 2019 10:36:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found`

Comment: Including dropping the explicit configuration and letting `spring-boot-starter-jpa` handle it for you, or only the Maven changes? I haven't manually configured Hibernate in so long that I don't remember exactly how to bootstrap it.

Comment: @chrylis I made the maven changes. where would I add `spring-boot-starter-jpa`?

Comment: Note that I'm not saying necessarily that you *should*, but you *tagged* this question `spring` `spring-boot`, yet you're not showing anything Spring-related in it, just a manual `main` startup of Hibernate. If you *are* using Spring, then you should let it do this for you; if not, then we should retag, edit your changes into the question, and wait for someone else to look at it.

Comment: @chrylis that was a mistake. it's a spring boot project.

Comment: In that case, your `main` class should simply say `SpringApplication.run(args)`, and Spring will take care of creating and injecting the persistence context. Note that XML configuration is considered obsolete in this case; follow the Spring JPA Getting Started Guide.

Comment: @chrylis wait I checked the tutorial and tried adding that and it didn't work. there might not actually be any spring involved. although spring boot and spring are mentioned in the video. maybe that's why I thought they were in the program. I think this is just regular hibernate